# Spring boot - Mockito being ignored in @Async function

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am writing tests for some async methods where I want to mock that an exception is thrown. These methods were synchronous and the tests we working fine until now that I made them async and for some reasy the mocked exception isn't being thrown.

My test:

```
@MockBean
private RestTemplate rest

@Autowired
private ServiceImpl mockedService;

@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void test1() {
    when(rest.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
            Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
            Mockito.eq(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)))
    .thenThrow(new MyException());

    this.mockedService.method();
}
```

The method I am trying to test:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate rest;

@Override   
@Async
public void method() {

   ...      

  try {
    rest.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MyObject>() {});
    responseEntity.getBody();
  } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
    log.error("Hello");
    throw (e);
  }
```

}

I am getting a `NullPointerException` because `responseEntity.getBody();` is being called when it shouldn't because the line above should cause an exception.

What's wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you ensuring to inject your mock using (`Mockito.initMocks(this)`) or run with JUnit to initialise the mocks `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`? Can you please provide more code?

Comment: @NagarajTantri I am using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: This solution has worked for me, could you please try once-
once:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824465/junit-testing-an-asynchronous-method-with-mockito/53839981#53839981

Comment: @Wrong would be great if there is [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Saurabha I tried that solution and I'm getting close thanks to it. Now the expection is thrown where I want it but I don't receive the expection I want in my test in the "expected"  side.